# C cast with MPI_Datatype

Tags: c, casting, mpi

I have a list of arrays stored in an opaque structure, and all their types are different. I have a function who give me them back, and I store them as `void *` arrays. I have an other function who give me their types as a `MPI_Datatype`.

When I manipulate theses arrays I cast them as `byte *`. But `byte` is a 8 bits long data type while my arrays type can be 16, 32 or 64 bits long.

So, do these can make some problems to access the good cell, and to 'use' the good amount of bits ?

If yes, is there a way to cast my arrays with the type stored as a `MPI_Datatype` ?

Here an example

```
void * intab;
void * out1tab;
void * out2tab;
int tag;
int j;
MPI_Datatype type;
Iterator vaiter;

IteratInit (inStruct, &vaiter);

while (IteratHasMore(&vaiter)) {

  tag = IteratCurTagNum (&vaiter);
  type = IteratCurTypeVal (&vaiter);

  ValueLink (out1Struct, (void**) &out1tab, type, tag));
  ValueLink (out2Struct, (void**) &out2tab, type, tag));

  intab = IteratCurValue (&vaiter);

  for (j = baseval ; j < nbr + baseval ; ++j) {
    if (flagtab[j] == 1) {
      ((byte*)out1tab)[j] = ((byte*)intab)[j];
    }
    else {
      ((byte*)out2tab)[j] = ((byte*)intab)[j];
    }
  }

  IteratNext(&vaiter);
}
```

Comment: I don't fully understand the question, but if you do not have the type, you cannot cast to it, obviously.

Comment: Your question is very hard to read. You write: "I have a list of arrays stored in an opaque structure, and all their types are different.". What do you mean by "their types"? The types of the array elements? Or the length of the arrays? Please give specific examples of the `MPI_Datatypes`. Are they element types or complete array types. In general how do you know the lengths of the arrays? What is `outNtab`? The term `void *` array is also ambiguous. What is `flagtab`? Pleas select your wording carefully. If you don't know the precise wording, please be more verbose.

Comment: @Zulan: "their type" => type of the array elements. `MPI_Datatype`: `MPI_INT`, `MPI_DOUBLE`... In this example the length is `nbr`, and I know it from some previous computations. `intab` is the tab store in the input data (`inStruct`), and `outNtab` are tab store in the output datas (`outNStruct`). "Are they element types or complete array types" => I don't understand. Why is `void *`ambiguous ?

Comment: MPI also knows vector data types, which is why it is so important to differentiate. A *"`void *` array"* would be something like `void* foo[]`. Be aware of the differences between a pointer to some data and an actual array. This may look like nitpicking to you, but it's important to avoid and misunderstandings. What is a "tab store" in your code? Please edit the clarifications in the question itself, not only in the comments.

Answer (score 3):

MPI datatypes are blueprints that tell MPI how to access and to interpret the content of the memory while constructing and de-constructing messages. MPI only cares about the layout of the binary content and knows nothing about the language type that corresponds to it, like whether it is an array or a structure of elements of the same type, and if it is a structure, how are its fields named. MPI datatypes are just handles to opaque structures managed by the MPI library.

While it is next to impossible to construct a language type out of an MPI datatype, at least not in statically typed languages such as C, it is still possible to query the internals of the MPI datatype and perform operations on the elements in memory. The procedure goes roughly like this (be warned - it is far from trivial):

- You should first obtain the datatype envelope using [`MPI_Type_get_envelope`](https://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v1.10/man3/MPI_Type_get_envelope.3.php), which gives you some basic information about the MPI datatype constructor call (the combiner) used to create the datatype. For structure datatypes created with `MPI_Type_struct` (deprecated) and `MPI_Type_create_struct` the combiner will be `MPI_COMBINER_STRUCT`. For contiguous (array) datatypes created with `MPI_Type_contiguous` the combiner will be `MPI_COMBINER_CONTIGUOUS` and for vector datatypes (strided blocks) created with `MPI_Type_vector` the combiner will be `MPI_COMBINER_VECTOR`. The full list can be found in the MPI standard or in the Open MPI manual page linked above.
- Given the result of `MPI_Type_get_envelope`, you should allocate large enough arrays of integers, offsets, and MPI datatypes, then call [`MPI_Type_get_contents`](https://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v1.10/man3/MPI_Type_get_contents.3.php) to obtain the actual parameters of the datatype constructor.
- As MPI allows practically unlimited nesting of datatypes, you should further recurse into each datatype until you reach a combiner of `MPI_COMBINER_NAMED`, which corresponds to a predefined MPI datatype. From there on, the basic language type follows trivially.

The above procedure will give you as a result the list of basic language types and their offsets relative to the beginning of the data buffer, the so-called *typemap*. You can use the offset of each element and a large `switch` statement to process it accordingly. You still won't be able to perform a cast in the source code. The latter could be possible in some dynamic scripting language that allows the construction of language types through the use of some introspection mechanism.

At best, if there are a limited number of MPI datatypes used in the program, you should employ a `switch` operator with the MPI datatype handle and cast separately to the corresponding language type, preferably not using some weird preprocessor macro solution.

Answer (score -1):

Something like this?

```
#define COPY_ELEMENT(type)                     \
do {                                           \
    if (flagtab[j] == 1) {                     \
      ((type*)out1tab)[j] = ((type*)intab)[j]; \
    }                                          \
    else {                                     \
      ((type*)out2tab)[j] = ((type*)intab)[j]; \
    }                                          \
    j += sizeof(type);                         \                                                                     
} while(0)

for (j = baseval ; j < nbr + baseval ; ) { // no j++, j is advanced by COPY_ELEMENT
    switch (type) {
    case MPI_BYTE:
        COPY_ELEMENT(byte);
        break;
    case MPI_SHORT:
        COPY_ELEMENT(short);
        break;
    case MPI_INT:
        COPY_ELEMENT(int);
        break;
    // all cases?
    }
}
```

(warning: did not test this)

Comment: I am reluctant to believe that this case requires a macro-based solution. Such a macro is horrible to debug and reason about and thus should be used very carefully.